# I can't create type object with variable type long on oracle database

Tags: mysql, oracle, object, oracle-type

I can't compile this code.
The long type not supported.

```
create type one_obj is object (art varchar(255),name varchar(255),surname varchar(255),number long,address varchar(255),team varchar(255));

create type one_tab is table of pelatis_obj;
```

what can I do to have a same type like long ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long is not supported in object types, please use CLOB.